# How to synchronize HTTP requests in a C server

Tags: c, sockets, http

I am trying to build a HTTP server in C using threads (each request is handled by a thread). This is the main part that accepts clients and start handling requests.

```cpp
while(1)
    {
        printf("\n+++++++ Waiting for new connection ++++++++\n\n");
        if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
        {
            perror("In accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        pthread_t thread; 
        //printf("%d\n", new_socket);
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, client, &new_socket);
        //sleep(1);
    }
```

and this is the client function

```cpp
void * client(void * socket){
        char buffer[5000] = {0};
        char responce[MAX_LEN] = {0};
        char path[100] = {0};
        long valread;
        int new_socket = *((int *) socket);

        if(valread = read(new_socket , buffer, MAX_LEN) < 0){
            printf("%s\n", "Error reading from client...");
            pthread_exit("crepat");
        }else{

        printf("%s\n",buffer);

        if(strlen(buffer) > 10){
            parse(buffer, path);
            if(strstr(path,"favicon.ico")){
                strcpy(responce, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n");
                int writeError;
                if(writeError = write (new_socket, responce, strlen(responce)) < 0)
                    printf("%s\n", "O Crepat aici la write wa");

                close (new_socket);
            }
            else{
                response_generator (new_socket, path);
                /*This function generate the header and resp and send them to the client through socket*/
            }
        }
        buffer[0] = '\0';
        responce[0] = '\0';
        path[0] = '\0';
    }
}
```

I think the problem is because of the big number of requests and because some of them are big files like images and js sometimes they enter in conflict with each others requests. I believe this is the problem because if I use the `sleep(1)` function (even if it takes 1 second for each particular request) it works fine but if there is no wait time between requests the page blocks in an infinite loading because some files could not be send and the client still waits for them.

My question is how do I keep the requests in an order but in the same time keep the server multithreaded so it could handle multiple requests from different clients? My first thought was to use the `Connection: keep-alive` header but this won't stop the server from accepting the request as if it is a new client, and if there is a workaround for this how do you know when you should stop reading from a keep alive request?

Comment: Passing in the address of 'new_socket' to pthread_create is bad.  A new incoming connection can overwrite new_socket before the handler thread can dereference its pointer parameter:(

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: And why is it working if I use sleep

Comment: You could mallocate a socket var, load it and pass it's address to create_thread().

Comment: Well, obviously, adding a sleep() in the loop reduces the chance of the accept overwriting new_socket before the handler thread can get at it.  It's a bodge, it's not guaranteed to work and adversely affects performance.

Comment: You have other issues.  If your client reads MAX_LEN bytes, 'buffer' is not guaranteed NUL-terminated and your 'printf("%s..' is then UB.

Comment: Can you help me with mallocate a socket var? How would do this look in my case?

Comment: Your client is not handling its received data as a byte stream.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203837/discussion-between-mike-bear-and-martin-james).

Comment: HTTP is built on top of TCP and TCP clients MUST work correctly even if each call to read/recv returns having loaded only one byte into the buffer.  Your code expects a multi-byte message to be received in its entirety, every time.  That will not work.

Comment: The parsing is done correctly as sometimes the client loads all the data needed. I think you are right wit the passing the new_socket to pthread_create. But I don't know how to implement your idea

Comment: For dynamic allocation, Google 'C malloc' or enter 'man malloc' at your linux command line.  Also, you must free() the allocated var/struct/whatever before your handler thread exits.

Comment: There are many examples in the 'sockets' tag:)

Comment: but my `new_socket` is an integer how would I mallocate a copy after it?

Comment: I am sorry but I still can't get it. What should I pass to my pthread_create? I create a copy pointer for my `new_socket` using malloc and then pass it to the thread?
`int* th_socket = malloc (sizeof(int));   th_socket = &new_socket;`

Something like this?

Comment: Classic: `if(valread = read(new_socket , buffer, MAX_LEN) < 0){` Please look up operator precedence for `=` and `<`